# Number of ways to invest $\$20,000$ in units of $\$1000$ if not all the money need be spent

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Working through a combinatorics section currently and am working on this $2$-part problem. I have solved part $a$ quickly and will provide my work below but am having some trouble with part $b$ and seek guidance in how to proceed.

---

**Question Statement**

An investor has $\$20,000$ to be invested amongst $4$ possible investments. Each investment must be a unit of $\$1,000$. If all the money needs to be invested then how many investment strategies are available? What if not all the money need be invested?

---

**Part $a$**

This is a simple application of the formula for distributing $n$ identical objects into $k$ distinct boxes. The formula being used is $${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$$ Where we note that $n = 20$ since this is the number of available units of $\$1,000$ for investment and $k = 4$, the number of investments. Hence we find $${23 \choose 3} = \frac{23!}{3!17!} = 12,113,640$$

---

**Part $b$**

For this part, my first instinct is to check each combination from $\$0$ invested all the way up to $\$20,000$ and then sum the results. Which would look like: $$\sum_{n=0}^{20} {n + 3 \choose 3} = \sum_{n=0}^{20} \frac{(n+3)!}{3!(n-3)!}$$
However, the first $3$ terms of this sum would lead to negative factorials, which haven't been covered (though I imagine $-3! = -3 \cdot -2 \cdot -1$) and the odd terms would then lead to negative values for the overall term, which doesn't make sense in the context of counting combinations.

Am I on the right track with my line of thinking? What adjustments should I try and think about in order to make the sum representative of the reality of the problem? Or am I way off and the solution is something else entirely? Thanks for any insight provided!

Comment: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.) covers the first...and the second:  just introduce a new "investment", representing the cash which is not deployed in the other investments.

Comment: The negative factorial results from you applying the formula wrong. $3$ among $n+3$ is $\frac{(n+3)!}{3!n!)}$

Comment: Per the comment of @lulu, the general approach to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_k \leq n$$ is to transform it to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_k + c = n ~: ~\binom{n + k}{k} ~\text{solutions}.$$  Note that since $x_1, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},$ and $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ you are **guaranteed** that in the second equation, the variable $~c~$ will **also** be $~\in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Comment: @lulu Ahh yes. Thank you! Such a concept was introduced in an example earlier in the section as well, I just didn't recognize this as a situation to apply that way of thinking.

Comment: @Keen Yes you are right. For some reason I kept using $20$ instead of $23$ in the difference foactorial term in the denominator. Likely just defaulting to using $n$ from the problem statement when applying the formula for $n \text{choose} k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a work similar to your approach in part $a$ and same way as lulu commented. Assumed $20$ identical coins to be distributed among $4$ persons $A,B,C,D$. It is not necessary to spend all of the conins.

Assume $a$ is the number of coins to $A$ and similarly to other $(b,c,d)$

$a+b+c+d\leq 20$

Assume a variable $p\in [0,20]$. And the solutions to the above equation are similar to those,

$$a+b+c+d+p=20$$

Now you can apply your result from part $a$ which will give. $24 \choose 4$

> Assuming investing no money is considered a case.

Answer (score 0):

**A:** By the way, for part $1$, though you have written the formula correctly, your computation is way off !

$\binom{23}{3} = 1771$

**B:** Here I put a slightly different interpretation to
"What if not all the money need be invested" to mean that *at least one unit is invested*,

so adding the slack variable, the formula becomes $$\binom{n+k}{k} - 1 = \binom{24}{4} - 1 = 10625$$

[The $-1$ is for all the money going into the slack variable ]